# How does it come that a session does not work on some 64bit machines?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am using CodeIgniter. When I register a user from my browser, it stores the user in a session. The problem is, I sometimes log in from a 64bit machine and then I don't get the user details after registration. This only occurs on 64 bit machines.

According to my knowledge, sessions are server side so it should not cause errors from some machines.

So, I think it is an error when setting cookies. Are there any problems when setting cookies on 64 bit machines?

And I am using a firewall. Can a firewall block cookies and cause some problems?

Comment: What type of firewall are you using?

Comment: codeigniter has it's own sessions. Do you use $this->session or $_SESSION?

Comment: We need more information about the firewall.

Answer (score 2):

A firewall shouldn't block a cookie.  But, the internet settings for your 64bit machine might have something to do with blocking cookies.  Check these.

As [@Cez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263671/cez) has pointed out, a software firewall could block a cookie.  If you can clarify that you are using a software firewall, like Zonealarm, then I'd check these settings as well.

Comment: Software firewalls such as ZoneAlarm can block cookies

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a firewall can block cookies, especially firewalls that run on your machine. Your browser privacy settings can also block cookies.

I'd use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or similar to inspect the web traffic and see if the cookies are being set.

Answer (score 1):

CI sessions store the whole data in the cookie. This can create very large cookies.

It is possible that your firewall blocks this cookie. Since the problem only occurs sometimes it might depend on the content of the cookie.

Comment: please tell me what type of contents causes these types of problems :(

Comment: I don't know. If you let us know what firewall we are talking about and maybe even how you cookie looks like. Someone might help you. But right now I can just guess.